# Simple Bayesian network

Tags: r, bayesian-network

I have three variables:

- GENDER {“Male”, “Female”}
- AGE {“0-18”, “19-30”, “30-60”, “60+”}
- REGION {“Europe”, “Asia”, “Africa”, “America”}

From the literature I “know” that:

**Males** who live in **Asia** and who fall into **19-30** age group have 5% probability of having certain disease. 
**Males** in general have 3% probability of having the same disease
**Asian** .. **teenagers** have average of 2%
**Americans** 4%
etc.

The point is that I have some knowledge and I want to record it in a network “format” and I would like to use that network in future.

I’m no R expert but I was reading lately about “bnlearn” package. It looks like it is exactly what I need but I can’t get my head around it! Am I on the right track? How do I specify my probabilities?

```
library(bnlearn);
net <- model2network("
[Gender.Male]
[Gender.Female]

[Region.Asia]
[Region.Europe]
[Region.America]

[Age.18.24]
[Age.24.30]
[Age.30.35]
[Age.45.50]
[Age.50.plus]
");
plot(net);
```

I actually have ~30 variables with up to 10 levels each.

Comment: @william, please stop spamming the site w/ tag edits. This shouldn't be done this way. You should raise the issue on meta.CV & we can make it a synonym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that a package like `gRain` may be more what you're looking for. This package has [an article explaining](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v46/i10/) it that should give you a flavor of how it works.

EDIT: I think you would do something like:

```
library (gRain)
region <- cptable (~region, values=c(0, 0, 0, 0), levels=c("Europe", "Asia", "Africa", "America"))
gender <- cptable (~gender + region, values=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels=c("Male", "Female"))
age    <- cptable (~age + region, values=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels=c("0-18", "19-30", "30-60", "60+"))
disease <- cptable (~disease + region + gender + age, values=rep (0, 2*4*2*4), levels=c("Y", "N"))

plist <- compileCPT (list (region, gender, age, disease))
grn1 <- grain (plist)

summary (grn1)
plot (grn1)
```

Where the 0 values should actually be your percentages.

Comment: Still no good. I spent hours trying to get it to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do I need a state for each attribute of the variable or is it could be achieved in some other way...

Comment: gRain seems to be dependent on graph package which is not available anymore. I hope bnlearn or similar packages can do the same

Comment: You get graph from the Bioconductor package. In the R Package Installer (Mac version, at least) choose BioConductor(binaries).

Comment: Hi Wayne. Thanks for that. I searched in the list of packages (from R installer) and there is no package called Bioconductor... do you have a direct link maybe?

Comment: I tried source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")

Comment: and got...Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
  cannot open the connection

Comment: `source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")` and then `biocLite(c("graph"))`, I believe.